# Compile my 32 bit project with C++ dll 64 bit

Tags: c#, c++

I have some legacy C# application ( 32 bit ) that work with some C++ 3rd party dll ( not com .. just simple unmanaged C++ )

One of those 3rd party dll just release new dll version - and this version is not 32 bit any more - its 64 bit.

I can't compile my code to 64 bit.

How can i continue work with this new version of 64 bit dll ?

Comment: Why can't you compile your code to 64 bit?

Comment: because this is legacy code and i just can't .. this will create more problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load a 64 bit DLL into a 32 bit process. Or indeed vice versa FWIW. It follows that you'll need two processes and IPC.

An out of process COM server would probably be the simplest way to proceed.

Comment: if i could have 2 process and IPC - i don't need any com server .. just simple process that run the 64 ( why com server ? )

Comment: COM just makes the coding easier. You get to call functions as normal and have the IPC implemented by COM. Your code doesn't even need to know that the library is out of proc.

Comment: this can be done by using pipe also - no  ? or i just don't get it

Comment: Yes it could be done that way too. Any IPC can be used.

Comment: so, is com server is better ? it witch way ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the simplest way would be to write a COM wrapper for the third party dll. I'd probably write that in c# because I'm lazy af but it could be C++ if you liked. Then you could call that wrapper, but it would have to be out of proc because you can't call across bitness in proc, but you knew that.